# NextJs Layout Login page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm covering app js with layout. I have the sidebar on the left and my pages on the right. But what I want is that the sidebar should not appear on the login page, how can I edit it?

_app.js
[image]

Layout.js
[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, anything text-based should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 1):

you can add a condition with `pathname` to showing the component or not

something like this:

```
const router = useRouter():

return (
   ...
   {router.pathname !== '/login' && <Sidebar path={router.route} />}
   ...
)
```

Comment: Yup i did like that its work but ı dont know this is the best solution thank you by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a HOC(Higher-Order-Component) called WithSidebar:

```
import Main from '../../components/Main/Main';
import Sidebar from '../../components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import classes from './WithSidebar.module.scss';

const WithSidebar = (Component) => {

    return props => (
        <div className={classes.WithSidebar}>
            <Sidebar />
            <Main className={classes.Container}>
                <Component {...props} />
            </Main>
        </div>
    );
};

export default WithSidebar;
```

And then export the pages that should include the sidebar like so:

```
import WithSidebar from '../hoc/WithSidebar/WithSidebar';

const MyPage = () => {

    return (...)
}

export default WithSidebar(MyPage)
```

I find this approach really cleaner than conditionally rendering based on the pathname.

Comment: man I had no clue this could be done, absolutely based

Answer (score 0):

If you have some pages that are protected and can be seen by logged in user than you would need Public and Protected Routes and you can show  in your Public routes only

If this is not the case then solution mentioned by @kaveh karami is good

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should use Option 4 of [the Persistent Layout Patterns article by Adam Wathan](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/) (the `getLayout` Pattern) to implement the layout and pass a prop to conditionally render the sidebar.

In this way, your Login / Register page controls the layout rendering

```js
// Layout.js
export default function Layout({ showSidebar, children, ...rest }){
  return (
    ...
    {showSidebar && <Sidebar />}
    ...
  )
}

export function getLayout(page, props) {
    return <Layout {...props}>{page}</DefaultLayout>
}


// Login.js
import { getLayout as getDefaultLayout } from './Layout.js'

function Login(){
  return (
    ...
  )
}

Login.getLayout = page => getDefaultLayout(page, { showSidebar: true})
```